# Comparing referrer url to the generated route url

Tags: symfony

I need to compare these two strings, so for example:

```
if($this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer') != $this->generateUrl('foo')) {}
```

The thing is that the referrer here gives me the full url address:

```
http://website.com/foo
```

And the generateUrl() method gives me only the following:

```
/foo
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an absolute url using:

```
 $this->generateUrl('route_name', $parameters, true))
```

`$parameters` can be `null` ... see the [API reference](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_generateUrl).